# scala ide (eclipse) and sbt project

Tags: java, eclipse, programming, ide, scala

I am using the last version of the scala ide eclipse http://scala-ide.org/

```
Scala IDE build of Eclipse SDK

Build id: 4.0.0-vfinal-20141216-1226-Typesafe
```

I have a project that I am able to run from the terminal with sbt:

```
    donbeo@donbeo-HP-EliteBook-Folio-9470m:~/Applications/scala_workspace/progfun-quickcheck$ sbt
[info] Loading project definition from /home/donbeo/Applications/scala_workspace/progfun-quickcheck/project/project
[info] Loading project definition from /home/donbeo/Applications/scala_workspace/progfun-quickcheck/project
[info] Set current project to progfun-quickcheck (in build file:/home/donbeo/Applications/scala_workspace/progfun-quickcheck/)
> test
[info] + Heap.min1: OK, passed 100 tests.
[info] + Heap.min2: OK, passed 100 tests.
[info] + Heap.min3: OK, passed 100 tests.
[info] ! Heap.sort1: Falsified after 1 passed tests.
[info] > ARG_0: List("0")
[info] + Heap.minMeld: OK, passed 100 tests.
[info] Quic..........
```

I have tried to import this project to eclipse running :

```
ickcheck$ sbt
[info] Loading project definition from /home/donbeo/Applications/scala_workspace/progfun-quickcheck/project/project
[info] Loading project definition from /home/donbeo/Applications/scala_workspace/progfun-quickcheck/project
[info] Set current project to progfun-quickcheck (in build file:/home/donbeo/Applications/scala_workspace/progfun-quickcheck/)
> eclipse
[info] About to create Eclipse project files for your project(s).
[info] Successfully created Eclipse project files for project(s):
[info] progfun-quickcheck
>
```

and then I have imported the project into eclipse. 
When I try to run the project from eclipse I get the following error:

```
WARNING: -p has been deprecated and will be reused for a different (but still very cool) purpose in ScalaTest 2.0. Please change all uses of -p to -R.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at scala.tools.eclipse.scalatest.launching.ScalaTestLauncher$.main(ScalaTestLauncher.scala:20)
    at scala.tools.eclipse.scalatest.launching.ScalaTestLauncher.main(ScalaTestLauncher.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.hd$1()Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.argTooShort$1(Runner.scala:1010)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.parseReporterArgsIntoConfigurations(Runner.scala:1024)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:627)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.main(Runner.scala:573)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.main(Runner.scala)
    ... 6 more
```

My understanding is also that the version of ecplise that I am using should have its own sbt plugin so maybe that can make things easier.

So how can I run the project from eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this problem similar to that one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701992/exception-occurs-when-running-scala-test-from-eclipse ?
Error is totally the same.

The solution from there:
"Check your classpath; in particular check that the version of scalatest you're depending on is compiled for scala 2.11, not 2.10." - by lmm.